# send a file from a C Server to a client that uses curl

Tags: c, curl, server, client

I wrote a C server to which clients connect using command line curl. Among other things, clients can download files from the server.
What kind of response should I send to the client's request, to make sure that curl stores the file?

Comment: "libcurl is a free client-side URL transfer library,[6] supporting cookies, DICT, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP (with HTTP/2 support), HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, HTTP proxy tunneling, HTTPS, IMAP, Kerberos, LDAP, POP3, RTSP, SCP, and SMTP. The library supports the file URI scheme, SFTP, Telnet, TFTP, file transfer resume, FTP uploading, HTTP form-based upload, HTTPS certificates, LDAPS, proxies, and user-plus-password authentication.", This is way too broad and even if you limit your question to one of the previous protocol, that would still be too broad.

Comment: I have no control over the client.
My code only includes the server that receives http requests from curl and sends replies.
So my server receives a request from the client that wants to download a file.
I do not know how to format the response to be sent to the client, so that curl used by the client, store the required file on disk.